# Trying to push API results to an array but returns as empty

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to loop through an array and push the results to an array but the array returns as empty

```
const actionOpportunities = result.data.opportunities
const actionArray = []


for (let opportunities of actionOpportunities){
  const currentIDs = opportunities.id
  axios.get('apiURL.com='+currentIDs,clientGet)
  .then((results)=>{
    const actionsResult = results.data.actions

    actionArray.push(actionsResult)
  })
}

console.log(actionArray)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `results.data.actions` is defined? What happens when you console log out `results.data`? Also, you should `console.log` after you push (while still in the for loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `actionArray.push` will be execute *later*. Axios return a promise, and the `then` callback that you pass to push data to `actionArray` is executed *after* that `console.log(actionArray)`.

To solve it: wait for all those promise to resolve, you can use `Promise.all`, and at that point you can collect all the results.

Something along the lines of:

```
const promises = []
for (let opportunities of actionOpportunities){
  const currentIDs = opportunities.id
  promises.push(axios.get('apiURL.com='+currentIDs, clientGet))
}

Promise.all(promises).then(allResults => {
  console.log(allResults)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with async/await:

```
const actionOpportunities = result.data.opportunities
const actionArray = []

(async () => {
  for (let opportunities of actionOpportunities){
    const currentIDs = opportunities.id
    const res = await axios.get('apiURL.com='+currentIDs,clientGet)

    actionArray.push(res.data.actions);
  }

  console.log(actionArray);
)();
```

Or if you don't want to call the requests one at a time:

```
const actionOpportunities = result.data.opportunities
const promises = []

for (let opportunities of actionOpportunities){
  const currentIDs = opportunities.id
  const promise = axios.get('apiURL.com='+currentIDs,clientGet)
    .then(res => res.data.actions);
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a timing issue, the `console.log();` is being run before the logic inside the `.then()`. Hence looking like the data has not been pushed. Try the following.

```
.then((results) => {
    const actionsResult = results.data.actions
    actionArray.push(actionsResult);

    console.log(actionArray); // should be defined here.
});
```

Comment: This allowed me to log the actionArray, but how would I add the completed array into res.render further down the page?

Comment: I cant see further down the page unfortunately, but hopefully this has answered the question you posted :)

Comment: const actionOpportunities = result.data.opportunities
const actionArray = []


for (let opportunities of actionOpportunities){
  const currentIDs = opportunities.id
  axios.get('apiURL.com='+currentIDs,clientGet)
  .then((results)=>{
    const actionsResult = results.data.actions

    actionArray.push(actionsResult)
    console.log(actionArray)
  })
}

res.render('index', { 
renderActions : actionArray
})

Comment: Sorry I have helped with the bit that made sense to me, Im yet to know the ins and outs of express. Maybe check https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render